# DataGridViewComboBoxCell takes several clicks to bring up menu for another cell. Advice on speeding up the process?

Tags: .net, datagridview

In order to bring up the menu for a DataGridViewComboBoxCell, I first have to click:
1) the row of the cell I want to edit
2) within the cell I want to edit
3) the I want to edit again, in order to open the ComboBox for the cell.

If another cell is already selected, the first click will close the already-active ComboBox, then 3 more clicks will then be required in order to open the ComboBox.

Seeing as nothing like this level of activity is required in order to click a DataGridViewButtonCell (DGVButtonCells respond to the first click, second if there was already a menu open), can anyone suggest a simple way of getting a class deriving from DataGridViewComboBoxCell to have the same level of responsiveness as DGVButtonCell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting the EditMode to EditOnEnter (either in the code or on the Properties page of the DataGridView). This should open it on the first click.

```
dataGridView1.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer create problem on row selection

You can achieve this by subscribing for the EditingControlShowing event of the grid and there for control of type ComboBox

```
ComboBox ctl = e.Control as ComboBox;
ctl.Enter -= new EventHandler(ctl_Enter);
ctl.Enter += new EventHandler(ctl_Enter);
```

And in the Enter event, use the property

```
void ctl_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as ComboBox).DroppedDown = true;
}
```

DroppedDown indicates as the name suggests whether the dropdown area is shown or not, so whenever the control is entered this will set it to true and display the items without the need of further clicks.